# How to set a default directory for ask_open_folder() in Ruby Shoes?

Tags: ruby, shoes

I am writing a small app in Ruby using Shoes GUI. In this app user need to select several directories as import destinations. Is there any way to give a default path for *ask_open_folder()* (based for example on the last user selection), so the user do not have to start from main every time the function is called? This can be really annoying after selecting the fifth directory....